# Shortest bitstring whose infinite repetition is different after reversal

Tags: string, finite-automata

[Marvin Minsky](http://web.media.mit.edu/~minsky/) asked me the following question during my oral exam:

> As an ant walks it prints a binary number (e.g., 101) every time it takes a step.  What is the minimum length, in digits, the binary number can be for it to be possible to tell which direction the ant is traveling without looking at the beginning or end of the string? The ant tells you the binary number.

Example: The ant's binary number is 101 and, hence, the ant leaves a trail that looks like this: 101101101101101101101.  Note that there is no way to tell which way the ant is traveling.  Hence, this particular number does not work (but there may be a three digit binary number that does).

Example: The ant's binary number is 011 and, hence, the ant leaves a trail that looks like this: 011011011011011011.  Again, there is no way to tell which way the ant is traveling without looking at the ends of the string.

What is the answer to this question?  Note that the answer cannot just be an example of a binary number that works. The answer needs to include a proof that no binary number of length less than n-1 will work where n is the length of the example binary number that works.  A proof by exhaustive enumeration is ok, but unpleasant. :)

Comment: Are you asking for a rigorous mathematical proof, or simply name dropping?

Comment: Why does the first trail not go "101101101101101"?

Comment: Voted to close as "not programming related". You might want to try a math forum for questions like this

Comment: The examples assume that the ant will print the same number at each step, which the question does not explicitly state ('a binary number' does not definitively mean it will be the same number).  Is this a issue with the wording of the original question, or an assumption you're making for these examples?

Comment: The question seems to be missing something.  What indicates direction?

Comment: @John You are right.  Edited.

Comment: @Mark Yes, it prints the same binary number.  That's why the ant can tell you what the number is.

Comment: @Alan Let's say the ant is printing the letters "xyz". If it prints "xyzxyzxyzxyz" you know it is going left to right.  If it prints "zyxzyxzyxzyx" you know it is going to right to left.

Comment: @gnp I'm asking for a rigorous proof.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this was closed.  The question was clear.

Comment: i'm more impressed by the talking ant!

Comment: The number in question, when reversed, can not be a substring of itself appended to itself (e.g. 011 does not work because 110 is part of 011011). The only way to achieve that is in binary is (a) have different digits on both ends of a number; (b) have them differ from neighboring digit; and (c) have inner sequence not "mirror" itself either by itself or when coupled with either of end digits. That's impossible for any number with less than 6 digits (easy to see). The answer, therefore, is 6. Example of the number in question is `100110`.

Comment: A bit sequence A=(a[0],...,a[n-1]) of length n is ant-symmetric iff there exists j so that A=(a[j],a[j-1],...,a[0],a[n-1],a[n-2],...,a[j+1]), i.e. for all i<n a[i]=a[(j-i) mod n].  What is the largest n so that all bit strings of length k<=n are ant-symmetric?  (a bitstring of length n+1 exists that is *not* ant-symmetric).

This is easily answered via enumeration.  In checking a bit string for ant-symmetry, if you've seen a rotation of it, or its reverse, or its complement (swapping 0 for 1 and vice versa), you can be assured that the ant-symmetry is the same.

Comment: Nice proof, Chss.  I was thinking that 6 was sufficient, because you can easily encode the "xyz" example with 2 bits for each of the 3 symbols.  It's interesting that Huffman coding: x=0 y=10 z=11, doesn't work, because on shifting/reversing, you lose the boundaries.

Comment: when is a closed question not closed? when people answer in the comments. fight the power! :)

Comment: @ ChssPly76 Your SO info is minimal.  Tell us about yourself.  Do you have a blog, website, twitter, facebook, etc.?

Comment: "Unknown (google)" complaining about minimal info in SO profile - now that's irony for ya :)

Comment: @ChssPly76 Not a complaint.  Just a query.  :)  I respect your intelligence and privacy, but, dammit, I'm about to launch a glorious startup and I need people like you! :)

Comment: Why, thank you, but I'm already a part of glorious startup :) It's in stealth mode for the time being - hence the absence of identifiable information for now.

Comment: @ChssPly76 When is it coming out of stealth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach would be to depart from binary numbers. Rephrase the question as "What is the shortest possible pattern which is directional if one is allowed to use any number of unique symbols?"

The answer here is 3 (for example A;B;C or #;&;@) since 2 does not work. So when you have a pattern like ABC is becomes clear in which direction the ant is walking.

Either ...CABCABCABCABCAB...  (from left to right)
Or     ...CBACBACBACBACBA...  (from right to left)

Now, how many Binary digits do we need to write a pattern of 3 symbols in Ternary (base-3)?

Two Binary digits allow you to write a single Quaternary (base-4) digit, which is the first base higher than or equal to 3.

Thus: (2 digits-per-symbol) multiplied by (3 symbols) = 6 Binary digits.

Comment: While this gets the correct answer, I'm not sure it's sound. First, with 2 bits you are wasting the fourth possible symbol, so it "could have been" that the overall pattern can be represented in fewer than 2*numSymbols bits. Second, the bitwise reversal and one-bit shifts mean a simple two-bit code breaks: for example if A=00,B=01,C=10, then ABC… is 000110… which does not have the desired property. A=00,B=10,C=11 is a specific instance which does not have this problem, but you haven't shown that this works in general.

Comment: The actual answer is AB AB AB.

Comment: This answer (almost) proves that 6 binary digits are enough, but it doesn't prove that you can't do it with fewer digits.

Answer (score 2):

ChssPly76 has the correct answer (IMHO) in the comments above.

6 digits, example 100110.